# How can I properly see lyrics in DeaDBeef?

Tags: sound, lyrics, deadbeef

The solution should be the [Infobar plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/deadbeef/files/plugins/0.5.1/ddb_infobar-1.1.zip/download) - but in my case it doesn't look properly.
It should look like this (from the author's site)
[image: deadbeef whith infobar as should be]

but instead it looks like this, with a large empty space above the tabs:

[image: deadbeef whith infobar error]

Does anybody knows a solution or has the same problem?

Comment: The top picture looks like unity - what desktop environment are you using?

Comment: Xfce -Xubuntu 11.10

Comment: The latest DeaDBeef 0.5.5 doesn't seem to have this problem to the same extent: with just the Infobar plugin, it's ok now. Nevertheless, the problem reemerges if I use also the File Browser plugin, and I need that too. (An workaround would be to use a static portable build just for lyrics and the older version for file browser.) The top picture is the plugin author's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest DeaDBeef 0.5.5 doesn't seem to have this problem - the empty space disappears and the player looks fine with lyrics: but only as long as the File Browser plugin (or maybe some other plugin) is not used. Similar problems with other plugins are very possible.
The cause of this is explained by the author of infobar ([here](https://bitbucket.org/dsimbiriatin/deadbeef-infobar/issue/9/empty-space-above-tabs-when-using-infobar)) as follows:

"Unfortunatelly, deadbeef doesn't provide API which allows to integrate third-party UI plugins into its interface (situation gonna be changed with release of version 0.6.0). In this situation infobar and filebrowser plugins use hacks to integrate themselves into deadbeef's interface and can't work together."

In v. 0.5.6 the Filebrowser and the gtk2 version of Infobar have the same incompatibility. But there is a gtk3 version of Infobar, and Deadbeef v. 0.5.6 has a gtk2-gtk3 GUI switch.
[image]
 Installing Infobar gtk3 and the File-browser, which is gtk 2, will result in using the two plugins alternatively: in the gtk2 GUI of Deadbeef only the file-browser will be visible, in the gtk3 GUI, only the Infobar. Switching between GUIs will switch between plugins too.

When lyrics are not found by Deadbeef/Infobar, use Foobar in wine and install the [lyrics grabber addon](http://code.google.com/p/lyricsgrabber/downloads/list). 
[image]
[image]

But usually would not need that (the difference with Foobar is that it embeds the lyrics into the file: Deadbeef displays them from internet)

[image]

Comment: The question will be deleted after the anticipated changes in v. 0.6 of DB.