# How to convert audio files in Deadbeef player?

Tags: sound, convert, deadbeef

I t looks like Deadbeef player should convert between different audio formats just by right-clicking and selecting "Convert"

[image]

[image]

But after that and a few seconds of delay as if working nothing happens.

Has anybody used it successfully and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [deadbeef player's](https://sourceforge.net/projects/deadbeef/) .deb package has some errors in it's control file. It does not properly lists it's dependencies for some of it's components. For example, conversion to .aac format from .mp3 format requires `faac`, but it doesn't list that.

I played it from terminal and tried to convert a .mp3 file to .aac file. The output is given below:

```
anwar@anwar:$ /opt/deadbeef/bin/deadbeef 
starting deadbeef 0.5.6 [static]

......
......

selected output plugin: ALSA output plugin
INFO: loading playlist Default
INFO: from file /home/anwar/.config/deadbeef/playlists/0.dbpl
convgui: gtkui plugin not found
plugin Converter GTK3 UI failed to connect to dependencies, deactivated.
plugin Shellexec GTK3 UI failed to connect to dependencies, deactivated.
gtkui: found cover-art loader plugin
```

And when I clicked on the convert button. The output was as follows:

```
converter: will encode using: faac -w -o "/home/anwar/fdfd.mp4" -
sh: 1: faac: not found
converter: write error (-1 bytes written out of 8000)
```

Which clearly indicates, the conversion requires `faac` package which isn't installed and wasn't in it's dependency list either!

I installed `faac` package with this command

```
sudo apt-get install faac
```

and after installation, the conversion successfully completed and the output was as follows:

```
converter: will encode using: faac -w -o "/home/anwar/fdfd.mp4" -
Freeware Advanced Audio Coder
FAAC 1.28

Quantization quality: 100
Bandwidth: 16000 Hz
Object type: Low Complexity(MPEG-4) + M/S
Container format: MPEG-4 File Format (MP4)
Encoding - to /home/anwar/fdfd.mp4
 frame | elapsed | play/CPU
  2640 |     2.5 |   24.06x
```

### The list of packages you need for conversion:

- For AAC - `faac` package. Install it with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install faac
  ```
- For FLAC - `flac` package. Install it with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install flac
  ```
- For MP3 - `lame` package. Install it with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install lame
  ```
- For MS RIFF WAV - No package is needed
- For MusePack - `musepack-tools` package. Install it with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install musepack-tools
  ```
- For Ogg Vorbis - `vorbis-tools` package. Install it with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install vorbis-tools
  ```
- For wavpack - `wavpack` package. Install it with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install wavpack
  ```
- For TTA - I didn't find a package for it. But it is very easy to get or compile from source.

  1. Go to [this Ubuntu forum post](https://sourceforge.net/projects/deadbeef/).
  2. [Download the attached source of `ttaenc` package](http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=186473&d=1300479972).
  3. Extract it to your home directory.
  4. Open a terminal and go to the extracted folder.
  5. Use these commands to install it

     ```
     make
     sudo make install
     ```

     Now, you can use the TTA conversion also.

---

<sup>For TTA conversion: Credit goes to [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10574630&postcount=2)</sup>

---

To get the proper file names and to set output location:

[image]

`%a - %t [%l]` will produce something like **Artist - Title [1:23]**. More on title formatting, [here](https://github.com/Alexey-Yakovenko/deadbeef/wiki/Title-formatting).

Comment: thnx, but could you try also for other formats and just add a few more lines like `sudo apt-get install faac` for the other common formats like mp3, ogg, flac? (i guess at least ogg format should have been natively supported, and i cannot convert to ogg)

Comment: if you are interested in this kind of stuff, i could suggest a small recent discovery: foobar2000 in its naked version (with just the native addons) used in wine is as light as deadbeef and still has a lot of features like getting tags from freedb, converting,and many others. i was using foobar with facets addon and it was heavy, not as much for the addon as for the fact that it involved adding a big load of files into the media library. but now seeing how light it is i feel like preferring foobar to deadbeef when not using  the media library

Comment: @cipricus I've updated the answer with all the necessary packages. Check the update

Comment: If only Deadbeef didn't say "Built-in" for codecs that aren't, you know, built-in.