# How to edit/add converter options in DeaDBeeF?

Tags: sound, convert, deadbeef

DeadBeeF can convert audio files easily.

(For a solution to a possible problem, see [How to convert audio files in Deadbeef player](https://askubuntu.com/a/206201/47206).)

There are different options but they are not editable

[image]

and new converting options can be added and edited

[image]

What command should I add there for a different FLAC level of compression for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact the options **are** editable: you cannot remove the built-in options, but you can add modified versions of them by saving the changes under a new name. (You cannot make changes and save under a pre-existing name.)

So, the easiest way to add convert options is to use the '**Copy**' button and then modify the commands and titles.

For FLAC:

Select [Built-in] FLAC (compression leve 5) --> Copy --> Title: `flac compression level 8`, command line: `flac -o %o -8 -ignore-chunk-sizes -`
--> Ok

See `flac -h` in Terminal for variables. 0 is the largest file (best quality) and the fastest process, 8 is the smallest file (best compression) and slowest process.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Similarly for the other formats.