# Is there a music player that doesn't play video or show photos?

Tags: software-recommendation, music-player

I want a music player that can't play video or show photos. I don't have any other requirements.

Are there any music players that fit my description?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate question? Does any of the suggestion here help?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/8444/stupid-simple-music-player

Comment: looking them up right now, some of them I've already declined but some look promising like deadbeef. Deadbeef almost cut it, but the lists are too hard to easily use.

Comment: Could you explain *why* do you want a music player that can't play videos or show photos?

Comment: @LukasStejskal A player that plays video awesome is VLC but if you want to listen to music, then it doesn't work. you don't have a library or any other function that you think is standard! IF we take Itunes it has a library and is very easy to use and have all the functions you need. But when you try and play video it's just horrible to use. That's why I just want a player to do one thing awesome! instead of everything mediocre.

Comment: @Alvar I see. Yeah, I also prefer if a program does one thing and does it right. While it doesn't meet your requirements, I use *mplayer* both for movies and music, and I think it's awesome for both purposes :). Cons: no GUI by default, it runs from console (which suits me, but might not work for everyone).

Comment: @LukasStejskal I like subsonic, because the GUI is in the browser and it's very easy to use. Sadly some Linux users hate Java so it might not work for everyone.

Answer (score 8):

[Audacious](http://audacious-media-player.org/)

Install via the terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install audacious
```

or through the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 4):

[Foobnix](http://www.foobnix.com/?lang=en) is similar to DeadBeef (both are clones of foobar2000), and you might like it more.

Answer (score 3):

[Clementine](http://www.clementine-player.org/) is a fantastic audio player with a great UI and playlist system. Without a doubt my favourite music player I've ever used. Very stable and useful.

Install via the terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install clementine
```

or use the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 3):

Potamus is an extremely lightweight GTK-based audio player with a simple interface and an emphasis on high audio quality. -- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+package/potamus

Install via the terminal with:

```
 sudo apt-get install potamus
```

or through the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

[image]

Actually it seems to play also the audio of a video file, but just the audio, not the picture ;)

Comment: A tip: the installation will ask you to enable `realtime priority` for jackd. You *may say no*, the program will still work fine.

Answer (score 3):

For me nothing comes close to [Guayadeque](http://guayadeque.org/). And even though it has lots of features, it can't play video or show photos and probably it never will.

Install via the terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install guayadeque
```

or using the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: How do I install it? is it in the repos? Or do I have to build it from a source?

Answer (score 2):

[gmusicbrowser](http://gmusicbrowser.org) is awesome :-)

Install via the terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install gmusicbrowser
```

or through the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 0):

### [Sub Sonic](http://Subsonic.org)

One of the best arguments why you should use subsonic is that you can stream music to any client that you want you just have to create your own subdomain like (http://yourname.subsonic.org) and your off.

It's a music player that is easy to use and can be remote managed outside the network.
It's coded in Java and supports a lot of platforms! :)